# Can you make this Many to Many script more dynamic?

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql, linq-to-objects

This is just my simple way of making a many to many relationship, but i would like something that makes it easy to create many to many, I have wished i could make a method return type anonymous, that would open some doors. But i am noot good with anonymous types, Yet!

Hope you can help !

What do you guys do when you need

```
private class Ids
{
    public int Id;
}
```

.

```
...
```

. And in some method:

```
IList<Ids> objIds = new List<Ids>();

var q = from c in dt.FK_Tags_Blogs
        where c.BlogId == someId
        select c.TagId;

foreach (var item in q)
{
    objIds.Add(new Ids { Id = item });
}

var w = from c in objIds
        join p in dt.Tags on c.Id equals p.Id
        select p;
```

David B: I Used your code like this:

```
    public static IQueryable<Tag> printTags(int id)
{
    DataClassesDataContext dt = new DataClassesDataContext();

     return 
      from b in dt.Blogs
      where b.Id == id
      from xr in b.FK_Tags_Blogs
      select xr.Tag;
}
```

Is that stupid?

Comment: You might want to look into how the guys at PLINQO modified the code generation on LINQ to SQL to avoid the intemediary join table in the LINQ to SQL Models: http://www.codesmithtools.com/plinqo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I do is:

```
  //linq to objects
IEnumerable<Tag> tags = 
  from c in dt.FK_Tags_Blogs
  where c.BlogId == someId
  join p in dt.Tags on c.TagId equals p.Id
  select p;


  //linq to sql with association properties
IQueryable<Tag> tagsQuery =
  from b in dc.Blogs
  where b.BlogId == someId
  from xr in b.FK_Tags_Blogs
  select xr.Tag;
```

Comment: WOW, I have no idea why that worked so well, thanks! How the heck is the seccond block of code connected to the first? Is it the xr.Tag at the end? ...How,?

Comment: I would use the first block with in-memory objects that are in separate collections and are only connected by values.  I would use the second block with linq-to-sql to read from the database - in order for it to work, Associations must be present in the dbml for those relational properties to exist.  PS: A lot of people are surprised that Where can come before Join in linq queries.

Comment: I updated the post, have a look, i will read your post a couple of times more :).

Comment: Ah so they dont work together! And by Association properties you mean Forgien Keys established in the database?

Comment: If foreign keys are present in the database, the designer will create associations to match. Otherwise, right click on some open space in the designer and Add Association.  Additionally, you may want to take a peek inside the dbml file (it's just xml) to see what is created.